# Clarification regarding batteries and ups

Tags: power-supply, batteries, ups

I am planning to setup a ups with 2 100ah/4h batteries next to my server setup.

Is it safe to work to work next to such high load batteries. Are there any health concerns that comes with working close to such high load batteries.

If there are any health concerns how can they be addressed.

Comment: What kind of batteries exactly? What technology, e.g.?

Comment: Lead Acid Batteries Exide company.

Comment: There are plenty of types of lead acid batteries, are they gel, AGM or free acid?

Answer (score 1):

For sealed lead acid batteries, there will be some minimum level of ventilation required; they can give off hydrogen gas which is not poisonous but mustn't be allowed to collect in an unventilated space. Not a huge problem; just ventilate it as well as you would a bathroom.

For older (maintainable) batteries - does anyone still make them? there are some precautions to be taken during battery maintenance, against acid splashes.

And of course, never carry aluminium ladders in a battery room! More realistically in your installation, all battery terminals and high current circuitry should be covered and inaccessible to anything metal except when being worked on. (Accidental short circuits can melt screwdrivers and, in a proper battery room, ladders.)

I think that's about it.

Comment: Yes, the high currents can spot weld a short (e.g. one's favorite crescent wrench) in place, making it difficult to remove the offending matter.

Comment: @Brian: Thanks for the reply. BTW its not a sealed battery but an un-sealed one. I was planning to set up the ups in my room next to my server setup which will be less than 2 feet from me. There is no ventilation round the clock but sometimes there is, can that cause problems.

Comment: Open lead acid batteries are definitely still sold, they are way better in some environments, in a car if you use it often and keep it warm but still want it to be usable for plenty of years.